# Change document root path on amazon services

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services

I have tried to change the default path where public ip points but still point to old directory

i have made change to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-deafult.conf

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/folder-name/public
```

but still points to /var/www/html/

made a change to **apache.conf to Allowoveride All**

do i need to make any other changes so that public ip points to **/var/www/html/folder-name/public**

Comment: Just a silly question, did you restart the Apache server after the change has been made?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can set the DocumentRoot. In the apache.conf file and in each of the Virtual Hosts' files. After the [httpd.apache.org](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html):

> httpd is also capable of Virtual Hosting, where the server receives requests for more than one host. In this case, a different DocumentRoot can be specified for each virtual host, or alternatively, the directives provided by the module mod_vhost_alias can be used to dynamically determine the appropriate place from which to serve content based on the requested IP address or hostname.

Remember to restart the server after the change has been made:

```
service apache2 restart
```

On the other hand, are you sure there is no cache on the way? Try to at least remove browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was permission to folder, i had set 777 permission to the folder i was giving default path. somehow it does not read if the permission is 777 so i changed the permission to 775 and it works